# Dynamic model binding in ASP.NET MVC Razor for multilanguage

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, multilingual

I want to use multilanguage structure in my ASP.NET MVC project. I have only two languages. So I keep two string fields in my DB for two languages (Eg: Header_EN and Header_TR).

I get my current language value from my .resx file dynamically (Eg: EN or TR).  But I have to use a dynamic model in my view. Normally I'm using this for single language:

```
    @model MyProject.Models.tTextTable

    <div class="TextDetailContainer">
        @Html.Raw(Model.MyTextDetail_EN)
    </div>
```

And I want to use a dynamic model value for multilanguage something like that:

```
    @model MyProject.Models.tTextTable

    <div class="TextDetailContainer">
        @Html.Raw(Model.("MyTextDetail_" + Resources.Language.CurrentLanguage))
    </div>
```

Is there a possible way to do this with this logic or is there another way to create dynamic model in Razor?

Comment: Isn't it possible to bind on the same model but fill the model based on current culture?

Answer (score 2):

If your model is `dynamic` then you can cast it to `IDictionary<string, object>` and get the value from it:

```
var dictionary = (IDictionary<string, object>)model;
var text = dictionary ["MyTextDetail_" + Resources.Language.CurrentLanguage] as string;
```

Although you should probably have one property `MyTextDetail` and set it in controller to appropriate localized value.